# Como hacer para tener un dato decimal de la diferencia de dos horas (HH,MM)

Tags: mysql, sql, base-de-datos

necesito tener la diferencia entre (hora de entrada) y (hora de salida), en formato decimal, para multiplicar por el precio por hora. He dado con una consulta, pero me gustaría saber si alguien la pueda reducir un poco, gracias de antemano.

```
SELECT (SELECT ROUND((SELECT MINUTE(worksheet.finish_time) / 60 +       
    (SELECT HOUR(worksheet.finish_time) 
        FROM worksheet WHERE worksheet_id = 17) 
    FROM worksheet WHERE worksheet_id = 17), 2)) - 
    (SELECT ROUND((SELECT MINUTE(worksheet.start_time) / 60 +   
    (SELECT HOUR(worksheet.start_time) 
        FROM worksheet WHERE worksheet_id = 17) 
    FROM worksheet WHERE worksheet_id = 17), 2) )as diferencia
```

teniendo en cuanta que tomo el registro numero 17 que tiene como hora de entrada 10:00 y hora de salida 18:30, me sale bien, 8,50, peor creo que se podria reducir un poco la consulta.

Comment: Ordene tu consulta, y no tiene absolutamente nada de logica. Si lo que seleccionas es simpre lo mismo, porque hay mil select y where?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

En lugar de convertir a horas decimales y restar, hazlo al contrario: resta y luego convierte:

```
SELECT hour  ( timediff( finish_time, start_time ) )
     + minute( timediff( finish_time, start_time ) )/60 diferencia
  FROM worksheet
  WHERE worksheet_id = 17
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, sabia que se podría hacer mejor, pero no tengo tantos años de experiencia como ustedes, me sirvió de mucho